Which equation does $j=ρv$ refer to?
I found this statement in my physics book, however I am unable to recall/ understand which equation this is, moreover the variables are not defined (I don't know what $v$ refers to). The relation $j=ρv$ should be applied to each type of charge carriers separately. In a conducting wire, the total current and charge density arises from both positive and negative charges:
j = p+v+ + p-v-
p = p+ + p-
Now in a neutral wire carrying electric current,
P = - P
Further,
v+ ~0 which gives p = 0
j = p_v
Thus, the relation j = pv does not apply to the total current charge density.
It would be great if you could explain this equation


You should really copy the text you screenshotted into the post. Not everyone can see the images.

Usually such equations are in the midst of all kinds of information about them. Have you read the whole chapter and previous chapters?

Unless I am misunderstanding, $j$ is the current density - charge density times charge velocity, as the equation specifies.
$v$ usually refers to velocity - I would be hard-pressed to find a physics equation that doesn’t use $v$ for velocity, or does use $v$ for anything else.

so what is this equation for?

Calculating the current density, which if you are studying electronics/EM physics you will use extensively.
